# Finding largest sum of consecutive numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, integer

I have a few questions for this program I am making to find the largest sum of consecutive numbers in a list. Mind you, this is not the same as finding the largest sum of contiguous integers in an array. Basically, given a list for ex. 2, -1, 3,4,9 .... etc up to 1 million, I need to find the largest sum of consecutive numbers (in the list given above, 3,4 are consecutive therefore sum is gonna be 7). So what I can understand is I need to have a loop that goes through the list and checks if the numbers are consecutive. I have based my loop around the fact that consecutive numbers when subtracted will equal -1, but my if statement always seems to get an ArrayINdexOutOfBounds error. To give an example, lets say the list is

```
1 2 3 4
3 -1 4 5
```

Here is my code;

```
public class ProgramCRedo {

//This method reads each line and checks for the largest sum of consecutive numbers in a list
//This method does not have a return value, information is outputted once it exists
//This method has one parameter, it is string list taken from the input file
public static void checkLine (String line){
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
    int sum = 0;
    int largestSum = 0; 
    int [] savedNums = new int [numbers.length];

    for(int i = 0; i<savedNums.length; i++) { //loops through the list
        savedNums [i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        if((savedNums[i] - (savedNums[i+1])) == -1) { //checks if numbers are consecutive
            sum += (savedNums[i] + (savedNums[i+1])); //if true, adds them up to a sum
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
//          System.out.println(savedNums[i]);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("input.txt"));
        String line;

        line = bf.readLine(); //reads line
        //String line1= null; //skips first line    

        while(line != null){    //keeps looping until no more lines     
            checkLine(line); // uses list to check each line in file
            line = bf.readLine();
        }
        bf.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){ // catches exceptions
        System.out.println("FILE NOT FOUND!");
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Reading Error!");
    }catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input Entered");
    }

    System.out.println("Program is complete");
}
```

Here are some of the questions I have

1. Why does my if statement in the method give me an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception?
2. The assignment stated that The list of integers for each test case will be given on a single line of text with a single space separating each integer in the list. You can assume that the maximum list size for each case will be 1,000,000 - where and how do I input this check for a maximum list of 1 million integers?

Thank you, this is in JAVA btw.

UPDATE: I figured out the array out of bounds issue. Now what happens is that when I print out the sum for the list example I gave here, I get 0, and -1. Which isn't correct. I'm going to try to trace this out but if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Comment: when `i` is at the max value that it can be `savedNums[i+1]` will exceed the length of the array

Comment: while reading line use "line = bf.readLine().substring(0,1000000);" this will limit your character length to 1Million and while creating the saveNums array you have created the array of equal length to numbers in input line but you are not adding those numbers in the array.

Answer (score 0):

> The assignment stated that The list of integers for each test case will be given on a single line of text with a single space separating each integer in the list. You can assume that the maximum list size for each case will be 1,000,000 - where and how do I input this check for a maximum list of 1 million integers?

The above statement tells you to assume that there will be 1 million integers incase you need to initialize an array of integers. But since in your case you are using `String[] numbers = line.split(" ");` you don't need to worry about this. But if your professor really wanted to exclude those lines that are more than 1 million integers then one way is to place a checking after `String[] numbers = line.split(" ");` (check the code below for details)

> Now what happens is that when I print out the sum for the list example I gave here, I get 0, and -1. Which isn't correct. I'm going to try to trace this out but if anyone has any ideas please let me know.

The above statement happens since your code will never be true for this line:

`if((savedNums[i] - (savedNums[i+1])) == -1) {`

The condition will never evaluate to `true` because you are just initializing your `savedNums` by doing `int [] savedNums = new int [numbers.length];` which means that if `numbers.length` is 3 then your `savedNums` will be `[0, 0, 0]` since the default values of an int array is 0.

You are only setting the value of each element of `savedNums` while you are iterating the loop by doing `savedNums [i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);` thus `savedNums[i+1]` will always result to 0.

Also doing `sum += (savedNums[i] + (savedNums[i+1]));` is incorrect because some elements will be added twice in `sum`.
Example if you have `savedNums = [1, 2, 3]` , then the value of the sum in each itewill be:
First iteration:

```
i = 0;
sum = 0; // initial
sum = sum + savedNums[i] + savedNums[i+1];
sum = 0 + 1 + 2;
sum = 3;
```

Second iteration:

```
i = 1;
sum = 3; // value after first iteration
sum = sum + savedNums[i] + savedNums[i+1];
sum = 3 + 2 + 3; // 2 was added twice
sum = 8;
```

Thus your `sum` will be 8 instead of 6.

I have modified your code so that it will work as expecting, just read the code comments 
for details.

```
public static void checkLine(String line) {
    String[] numbers = line.split(" ");
        if (number.length > 1000000) { //if line contains more than 1 million integers
                 return;
        }
    int sum = 0;
    int largestSum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) { // loops through the list
        int currentNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
        int nextNum = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i + 1]);
        if (nextNum - currentNum == 1) { // checks if numbers are consecutive
            // check if sum is 0, which means that this is the first time a consecutive
            // number is found
            // example [1,2,3,4]
            if (sum == 0) { // this will be true when currenNum is 1 and nextNum is 2
                sum = currentNum + nextNum; // since it is the first time a consecutive number is found add both
                                            // numbers
            } else { // this will be executed when currenNum is 2 and nextNum is 3
                sum += nextNum; // since it is not the first time a consecutive number is found only add the
                                // next number, no need to add the current number since it is already added in
                                // the above condition
            }
        } else {
            sum = 0;
        }
        if (largestSum < sum) {
            largestSum = sum;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Sample input:

```
1 2 3 4
3 -1 4 5
1 2 4 5
```

Output:

```
10
9
9
```